# Using regex with array

Tags: php, regex, joomla

I am new using regex expression. After much digging I came up with this code. I would like to know if this is the correct way.
I want to search in Joomla for some html tags with specific class and then replace the code between those tags. I want to use an array ($patterns) with tag and classes and another array ($replacements) with replacements values.

```
$body = JResponse::getBody();
$patterns = array
(
    array('a','logo')
    array('span','main')
);

$replacements = array
(
    array('<p>some text</p>')
    array('<p>another text</p>')
);

foreach ($patterns as $key => $value) {
$body = preg_replace('/(<'.$patterns[$key][0].' .*?class=".*?'.$patterns[$key][1].'.*?">)(.*?)(<\/'.$patterns[$key][0].'>)/', '$1'.$replacements[$key][0].'$3', $body); 
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Yuo really should use a DOM parser for this - http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Code review belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Jay Blanchard but being newbie, for now this isn't the easy way, at least initially?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy sorry for that

Comment: No, this is the harder way because of the regex involved and the fact that regex and HTML tags do not play well together @user4076077

Comment: @Jay Blanchard thank you for your advice

Comment: @Ohgodwhy to move to codereview.stackexchange.com i have to re publish it there?